# filtering rows with an select in query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I generate variable as object from a resulset of a SQL task. SQL task is basically a select myID from myTable query.

What I need to do is I have to filter other table using those IDs returned in the other one. I use an conditional split in the task flow but how can I achive to make it like an "Select In query" on tsql. what I mean is select from table2 where myOtherID in (x,y,z)

those x,y,z are as integer and should be what it is returned by the first query which are hold in my VarIds object variable.

thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the variable into a script task to loop over the values and transform your Result Set into a query in the form of a string.

Once you have your string query saved to a variable you can create a data flow task later in the control flow. It needs to start with an OLEDB source shape which will perform your select query.

In the OLE DB Source Editor set the Data Access Mode drop-down to "SQL command from variable" and select your variable.

That should do it.

Comment: It works fine but let me know something if possible, if I create a coma seperated string in my script task instead of full sql query, Can i use it to filter already existing datatable results? using conditional split, look up or any other tool?

Comment: You can use a lookup task to filter data. Instead of saving your filter results into a variable you could write them directly to a cache connection manager in a new data flow task. Then you can add a lookup task downstream of the data to be filtered which has connection type "Cache connection manager". Select your cache from before and link the column to filter on in the Columns screen and it should filter your data.